# Linux use second terminal in minimal iso

Tags: centos, terminal

I installed CentOS minimal iso, as you know there is only one    terminal in opening so I made everything within there but I want to know;

1. Can I open a second terminal window ?
2. I am downloading on this main terminal window, how can I just hide
   this process and go on typing. (I want it keep downloading at
   background but I don't want to see process, I want it let terminal
   free to my use again.)
3. Is there any tricks to manage linuxOS without gui. How can I make it
   more efficient?
4. I set shared folder in virtual box but can't reach the file
   `/media/..` how can I make it able to share folder with host machine

If I used desktop environment, these wouldn't be any problem, I am able to create with typing ctrl+shift+t but I am using minimal iso centos and there is only one terminal seems to useable.

Comment: With a "minimal" install, you have one of several console *virtual terminals*, which normally you can switch to new/old ones using control/alt followed by a function key.

Comment: Can you eleborate this a little? fir inst. I downloading a package while existing terminal getting packages from internet how can  I open (or switch) new terminal window ? which function key ? also type it as answer not comment please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a "minimal" install, you have one of several console virtual terminals, which normally you can switch to new/old ones using control/alt followed by a function key.

For instance, <kbd>control</kbd><kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>F2</kbd> (all three keys pressed at the same time) switches to the second virtual terminal, while <kbd>control</kbd><kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>F1</kbd> will switch back to the first virtual terminal.

Further reading:

- [7. Console switching](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Keyboard-and-Console-HOWTO-7.html) (The Linux keyboard and console HOWTO)

Comment: thats what I exactly looking for, thank you.

Comment: OSX doesn't have F1 and F2.

Answer (score 1):

1. Thomas Dickey already mentioned the possibility to switch between virtual terminals. In addition to that you can use *screen* or *tmux* to manage multiple sessions in a single window.
2. You can start processes in the background by attaching an '&' character like so:
   `wget example.com/example.html &`
   If the software is already running you can move it to the background with `CTRL+Z`. You can list processes running in the background with `jobs` and move them to the foreground with `fg <jobid>`
3. *screen* and *tmux* are great to improve productivity. You may also want to use software with a TUI (text-based user interface) such as midnight commander to manage your files.